# Cloudformation Attach instance to Auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

In my CloudFormation file, I created an instance, a Launch Configuration and an Auto Scaling Group.

```
  LogstashInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: LogstashInstanceProfile                 
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: chuongtest
      ImageId: ami-0cd31be676780afa7
      UserData:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: LogstashSecurityGroup
      SubnetId: subnet-0e5691582096fe1e6
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Logstash Instance      
  LogstashLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:  
      EbsOptimized: false
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: LogstashInstanceProfile
      ImageId: ami-0cd31be676780afa7
      InstanceMonitoring: true
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: chuongtest
      LaunchConfigurationName: LogstashLaunchConfiguration
      SecurityGroups: 
        - Ref: LogstashSecurityGroup
      UserData:                                          
  LogstashAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties: 
      AutoScalingGroupName: LogstashAutoScalingGroup
      AvailabilityZones: 
        - ap-southeast-1b
      DesiredCapacity: 1        
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: LogstashLaunchConfiguration
      MaxSize: 1
      MinSize: 1
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: "false"
          Value: Logstash ASG 
        - Key: Instances
          PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
          Value: Logstash
```

My idea is to create an instance, attach it to the ASG and use the ASG to keep the work continue.
But this code will launch 2 instances.

The first instances has userdata different from the later instances so I can not delete the instance.

I have looked in the documentation but I can not find anything make sense. Is there a way to configure in the template, or the only way is scripting?

Comment: You can't "attach" and instance to the ASG. You need to build it within the AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration. If there is data on the server you can't lose you can create an AMI of your original server, use that AMI in your launch configuration and then once it's been deployed, remove the LogstashInstance.

Comment: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html)
I see that there is a way to attach instance to the ASG, that I can create the ASG from that instance. But I can not find a way in cloudformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have looked in the documentation but I can not find anything make sense. Is there a way to configure in the template, or the only way is scripting?

It does not make sense, because its **not practical**. ASG will be launching instances only from the associated `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration`. Thus, there is not much sense on "manually" attaching instances in your cause the the ASG. ASG will **not re-launch** it when it fails.

If the "manually" attached instances gets terminated for some reason, e.g. hardware failure, ASG will launch a replacement based on the launch configuration.

> userdata different from the later instances

In this case the best would be to provide some **condition** in your `UserData` which would determine which version of your `UserData` to run.

Alternatively, just have **two ASGs**. One for the first instance, while the other group for the remaining instances.

Comment: I can manually attach instance to ASG, following this link 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html 
My idea is launch the first one with the first userdata, put it into the ASG, and the later instance launch when the first crash will use the second userdata.

Comment: @BlakeAsh Hi. You can still do this with just one UserData and one LaunchConfiguration. But the easiest would be to use external storage, e.g. S3 or EFS.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, external storage like EFS is my plan B because of its price. And how can I seperate the first and later instances with just one Userdata?

Comment: @BlakeAsh In your `UserData` you use AWS CLI or SDK to programmatically mount a volume. First instance, when launched will attach the volume  to itself and mount it. Then when it gets terminated and replaced, the second instance will do the same. And the process will continue as needed.

Comment: Yesss :( How could I forgot that way. Thanks a lot, I will make a quick test and tell you the results

Comment: @BlakeAsh No problem. If have some issues, please feel free to ask or make new question :-)

Comment: @BlakeAsh Oh. Just need to make sure that the volume and ASG are in same AZ. Volumes have AZ scope only.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, your advice make my template work, so it make my day too.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Having discussed via the comments I would highly recommend the approach of using [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) as it is designed for the workload design you're doing.

In addition it is multi AZ vs the approach of rotating a single EBS volume as instances fail in an autoscaling group which would not persist should the AZ fail and potentially lead to loss of data.

**Original**

If that first instance is different from the rest you should be careful about adding it to the autoscaling group (as you want it to persist), especially in how it handles the replacement of instances.

Autoscaling groups are designed to scale similar instances that are generally immutable, so by having your host in this autoscaling group it will be treated as if it is one of the other hosts.

> An Auto Scaling group contains a collection of Amazon EC2 instances that are treated as a logical grouping for the purposes of automatic scaling and management.

**If** you must add it to the autoscaling group here is the general approach:

- Create a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) which involves a Lambda attaching the EC2 to the ASG using [attach_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.attach_instances)
- Add [set_instance_protection](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.set_instance_protection) to your instance to prevent it being replaced during a scale in event (or the instance failing)

Also ensure you set both the `MinSize` and `DesiredCapacity` to 0 to remove any extra instance that gets launched.

As I stated earlier **you should not add this instance to the ASG if it can be avoided**, tt will probably lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not much different. In the first instance, i mount an EBS volume and use it. When the first die, the next instance which has different userdata can mount the remain EBS volume and continue the process.

Comment: Could you not perhaps share an EFS mount instead, that way you can autoscale with 1 instance but always using the shared EFS mount? :)

Comment: Yes, EFS was the second choice because of its price. But if i can not go with the EBS, i will change to EFS. But I think i can go with EBS with some scripting, but I want to find a official way

Comment: OK, I mean personally I would go with EFS as theres less scripting and it is designed to allow your instances to be immutable. The other advantage is that EFS is multi AZ, whereas the EBS approach is in a single AZ. If the AZ goes down you've potentially lost what you have :(

Comment: Yes Chris, EFS is an easier way. I think i will use it after this day but now I will try my best :D

Comment: OK, hope I helped. Let me know if you need any further guidance :)

Comment: Yes, you helped me to quit the rough road quicker :D And I really appreciate that